# Why can I not change the Sprite attribute directly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, null, attributes

**I accidentally cross posted when I tried to switch the site I was posting to.  Oops!
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120309/why-can-i-not-change-a-sprite-directly/120311#120311**

---

I am changing the Sprites on an array of Images.  I could think of two ways to go about it.  The first way being:

```
var images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
foreach(var image in images)
{
    if (!image.sprite)
    {
        image.sprite = GetMySprite();
    }
}
```

This way works perfectly.  But if I try to grab the sprite itself like so:

```
var images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
foreach(var image in images)
{
    var sprite = image.sprite;
    if (!sprite)
    {
        sprite = GetMySprite();
    }
}
```

It does not work.  The Sprite gets assigned, but it is not the original Sprite.  The Sprite attached to the Image remains null.

At first I thought, maybe Sprite is a struct? But it is not - it is a sealed class extending Object.  (And I don't think that would necessarily explain it anyways).

So why must I retain the reference to the Image when changing its Sprite attribute?

Comment: First you have `sprite` "point to" `image.sprite`. Then you have `sprite` "point to" whatever is returned by `GetMySprite()`. The `image.sprite` var remains unchanged.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That makes sense, thanks!  I was thinking that I sprite was  sharing the same pointer as image.sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both instances the sprite field is a reference to a sprite object. In your second example you create a local variable which is also a reference to a sprite object - that you initialise by copying the value from image.sprite. Note that "var sprite" is not a reference to "image.sprite" itself.

In the second example, you only modify the value of the local variable, leaving the original unchanged.

Comment: So I was thinking sprite = pointerToTargetSprite, then pointerToTargetSprite = NewSprite.  But what is really happening in those terms?  I get the jist of what you are saying, but it is still sorta going over my head, sorry.;

Comment: In pointer terms - you could look at it as both image.sprite & sprite are independent pointers that are pointing to the same object. When you assign to sprite, you are only affect that pointer. In C++ terms, what you would need for what you are expecting to happen is the image.sprite is a pointer to an object & the "var sprite" creates a pointer to a pointer (**) initialised to image.sprite - in which case modifying sprite has the effect of modifying image.sprite.